# Apache solr indexing slowdown over time

Tags: linux, performance, solr

We suffer from "slow down of solr's indexing performance over time"

We try to measure indexing throughput of SolrCloud. 8 SolrJ clients sends update request to a solr and each client has 20 threads. (Total 160 threads sends request to solr) We believe that throughput depends on disk I/O performance of solr machine.

The results are below :

[image: test result]

At first few time, solr uses full disk write ability. But IO amounts per time is getting lower over time. As the result indexing speed also slow down.

Test environment:

- 1 physical machine,
- 256GB RAM,
- RAID-0 data volume (11disk),
- 16core CPU.
- 1 collection,
- 1 shard,
- 1 rf,
- 60gb HeapSize,
- java8

Zookeeper is running on same machine.

CPU and network, zookeeper are not bottleneck.

Comment: @psyco Thanks for editing. Much better looking.

Comment: Thanks and do read the basic SO markdown to write your question in proper way.   :)

Comment: how many solr nodes? just one?

Comment: @Persimmonium We test on 1 solr machine.

Comment: We solved the problem. The key is disabling uniqueKey. There is no performance degradation over time after disabling uniqueKey. We suppose that cost of maitaining uniqueness is not cheap. PS. Our writing patten is only accumulating.